# javascript script unescape hangs IE and Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

The following script request seems to have problems in any browser except Firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Browser Delay</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("jquery", "1.4.4");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="logicbuy_ad">
            <!-- Problem is here!!!!! -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.symbiosting.com/LogicBuy/content-syndicate-laptopmag.php"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the script loads, even in an iframe, IE and Chrome seem to hangs until the script finishes.

Is there a way to load this script so that it will not stop/hang the browser?

Comment: you could maybe make an asynchronous call to the server to load the php file, and when it returns, you can then stick it on the page, perhaps? The delay is coming in getting the javascript from the server, so using AJAX makes sense, but I'm not quite sure how one would go about this.

Comment: I have tried several different methods using ajax, but the problem is that I need to attach the response to a specific tag and I'm not sure how to do that.
I've tried to use $.getScript and $.ajax({dataType: 'script', url: 'http://www.symbiosting.com/LogicBuy/content-syndicate-laptopmag.php'})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem only happens when the script is loaded from a local page. (ie. C:\Users{username}{Code Base}\index.html )

Once I hosted the file on IIS, the problem went away.

I'm still very curious as to why the script would hang when displaying the local file as opposed to the hosted version